# How to Remove a specific character from the end of the string in php

Tags: php, string, substr

How to Remove a specific character from the end of the string in php

```
$string = 'سلام-تست-است-';
```

i want change like

```
$string = 'سلام-تست-است';
```

so end of the سلام-تست-است we have Extra characters " - " and i want to remove it.

and this is my code :

```
 foreach($tag as $t){
            $t =  str_replace(' ', '-', $t);
            if(substr($t, -1) == '-'){
              $t   = rtrim($t,"-");
            }
            $insert_value[] = '("'.$content_id.'","'.$t.'","'.time().'")';
        }
```

$tag is my string .
any idea?

Comment: just use `$t = rtrim($string,"-");`. no foreach needed for it

Comment: i have too much $tag ! i should get one by one ! @TamilSelvan

Comment: `$tag` is a *string* or an *array*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `rtrim` does nothing if the character at the end was not found, you can simply run it without the `if` check:

```
foreach($tag as $t) {
    $t = rtrim($t);
    $t = str_replace(' ', '-', $t);
    $insert_value[] = '("'.$content_id.'","'.$t.'","'.time().'")';
}
```

Or even more reduced to:

```
foreach($tag as $t) {
    $t = str_replace(' ', '-', rtrim($t));
    $insert_value[] = '("'.$content_id.'","'.$t.'","'.time().'")';
}
```

However, this is just a hint to simplify your code. It should also work in it's current form as shown in the question, meaning the problem seems to be somewhere else.